# Rails 3 destroy multiple record through check boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have issue with multiple delete using checkboxes. when i m deleting multiple records it get s ids for checkboxes but it is passing a method name as parameter and shows me error.

here is my code,

```
  **In my Controller method :**
  def destroy
    @ticket = current_user.tickets.find(params[:ticket_ids])
    @ticket.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to tickets_url }
     format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end    


 def destroy_multiple
    Ticket.destroy(params[:tickets])

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to tickets_path }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

**In my index.html.erb**

<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_tickets_path, method: :delete do %>   
.
.
<td class="table-icon">
  <%= check_box_tag "ticket_ids[]", ticket.id %>
</td>
.
.
<%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>

**In routes.rb**

resources :tickets do
  collection do
    delete 'destroy_multiple'
  end
end
```

it shows me this error ::::

```
 Couldn't find Ticket with id=destroy_multiple [WHERE "tickets"."user_id" = 1]
```

passes arguement ::::

```
  {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "_method"=>"delete",
  "authenticity_token"=>"yHeRR49ApB/xGq1jzMTdzvix/TJt6Ysz88nuBEotHec=",
  "ticket_ids"=>["11",
  "12"],
  "commit"=>"Delete selected",
  "id"=>"destroy_multiple"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do

```
Ticket.destroy(array_of_ids)
```

Answer (score 4):

Step:1 **In routes.rb**

```
resources :tickets do
  collection do
    delete 'destroy_multiple'
  end
end
```

Step:2 In _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_tickets_path, method: :delete do %>   
   <td class="table-icon">
     <%= check_box_tag "ticket_ids[]", ticket.id %>
   </td>
  <%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
<%end%>
```

Stpe:3 In Controller

```
def destroy_multiple
  Ticket.destroy(params[:tickets])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tickets_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Ticket.where(:id => params[:ticket_ids]).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi, Update your Controller code likewise..

```
def destroy_multiple
 @tickets = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_ids])
 @tickets.each do |ticket|
 ticket.destroy
 end
end
```

Comment: where u use "@ticketsts" this???     this is correction and perfect code.... "Ticket.destroy(params[:ticket_ids])"