# Rails destroy multiple record through check boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

My issues are simillar with his
[Rails 3 destroy multiple record through check boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300596/rails-3-destroy-multiple-record-through-check-boxes)

it shows me this error

```
Couldn't find Ticket with id=destroy_multiple
```

So I changed my code like this

In **routes.rb**

```
 resources :tickets do
   collection do
     delete 'destroy_multiple'
   end
 end
```

**In mod.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_mods_path, method: :delete do %>
  <div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
    <table >
      <tr>
        <td>Delete</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Detail</td>
        <td>Material_Code</td>
        <td>Material_Name</td>
        <td>Material_Type</td>
        <td>Unit</td>
        <td>Storage_Lowerlimit</td>
        <td>Storage_Upperlimit</td>
        <td>Material_Unit_price</td>
        <td>Material_Balance</td>
        <td>Material_Total_value</td>
        <td>Material_Producer</td>
        <td>Material_Location</td>
      </tr>
      <% @mods.each do |mods| %>  

      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "mods_ids[]", mods.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "edit",  edit_mod_path(mods.id) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'detail', mod_path(mods.id)%></td> 
        <td><%=mods.code %></td>
        <td><%=mods.name %></td>
        <td><%=mods.version %></td>
        <td><%=mods.unit %></td>
        <td><%=mods.lowerlimit %></td>
        <td><%=mods.upperlimit %></td>
        <td><%=mods.unitprice%></td>
        <td><%=mods.totality %></td>
        <td><%=mods.totalprice %></td>
        <td><%=mods.producer %></td>
        <td><%=mods.storage %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
<% end %>
```

In **Controller**

```
def destroy_multiple
  Mod.destroy(array_of_ids)
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to mods_path }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

In **Model**

```
class Mod < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_xlsx

  attr_accessible  :name ,:code, :lowerlimit, :producer, :storage, :totality, :totalprice,   :version, :unit, :unitprice, :upperlimit

  has_many :feedbacks, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  validates :upperlimit, presence: true
  validates :lowerlimit, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :code, presence: true
  validates :code, presence:   true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end


def destroy
  Mod.find(params[:mods_ids]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "Material destroyed."
  redirect_to mods_url
end
```

Now I have new error when I when i'm deleting multiple records

**NoMethodError in ModsController#destroy**

```
 undefined method `destroy' for #<Array:0x2bf8678>
```

I take Markets's advice 
this is the second error's params

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Z8awZYzgdGXK5eptpe1Erxow3yBGqQU9r+8j2NW4L5M=",
 "mods_ids"=>["14",
 "15"],
 "commit"=>"Delete selected",
 "id"=>"destroy_multiple"}
```

Comment: For this particular situation you could try: `Mod.where(id: params[:mods_ids]).destroy_all` because `find(Array)` returns an array of records.

Comment: I take your advice and it shows new error. When I run it at first time, it gives a success flash but actually doesn't perform delete function. When I run it at second time, it shows error following.    `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ModsController#destroy

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: mods_products: SELECT        "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "mods_products" ON "products"."id" = "mods_products"."product_id" WHERE "mods_products"."mod_id" = 14` Is there a conflict between my inner join table and array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
def destroy_multiple
  Mod.destroy_all(id: params[:mods_ids])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to mods_path }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

It's similar to:

```
Mod.where(id: params[:mods_ids]).destroy_all
```

Don't forget to define correct routes (note `:mods` instead of `:tickets`):

```
resources :mods do
  collection do
    delete 'destroy_multiple'
  end
end
```

Comment: I take your advice and it shows new error. When I run it at first time, it gives a success flash but actually doesn't perform delete function. When I run it at second time, it shows error following.    `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ModsController#destroy

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: mods_products: SELECT        "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "mods_products" ON "products"."id" = "mods_products"."product_id" WHERE "mods_products"."mod_id" = 14` Is there a conflict between my inner join table and array?

Comment: Can you share your `Mod` model and `params` recieved first and second time?

Comment: Sure,here is the mod model `class Mod < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_xlsx
  attr_accessible  :name ,:code, :lowerlimit, :producer, :storage, :totality, :totalprice, :version, :unit, :unitprice, :upperlimit
  has_many :feedbacks, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  

  validates :upperlimit, presence: true
  validates :lowerlimit, presence: true

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :code, presence: true
  validates :code, presence:   true,
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end`

Comment: Sorry,I don't know how to give you params received first time because it doesn't show. This is second time error. `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"7K5c3JFgffUSE9boMaUQMAo2xRRuvWm226a1NYdcgmI=",
 "mods_ids"=>["14",
 "15"],
 "commit"=>"Delecte selected",
 "id"=>"destroy_multiple"}`

Comment: Please, edit your OP and add this info there, it's quite unreadable here in comments.

Comment: Sorry,I have changed my OP. :P

Comment: I updated the answer with some clarifications. Hope it can help you. Anyway, I think you don't need that `destroy` method in your model, it seems a typo.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Problems have been solved. Facts show that `destroy` method is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The facts show that my destroy method is unnecessary. When I delete it and annotate the duplicate resources method in route.rb, problems can be solved.

```
 # resources :mods
 resources :mods do
   collection do
    delete 'destroy_multiple'
   end
 end
```